# Networking Drivers "disappear" Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 16.04, lenovo

About four days ago after installing routine Ubuntu updates, my wireless networking (and I believe networking in general) does not initiate on boot. It takes on average 6 reboots before networking starts again. Not sure if I am doing something on the user end that initiates a change.

Here are some logs recorded while networking was not working:

```
rfkill list
```

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280

ifconfig
```

```
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:64472 (64.4 KB)  TX bytes:64472 (64.4 KB)
```

```
iwconfig
```

```
enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

```
        *-network DISABLED      
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 04
       serial: 3c:97:0e:40:5d:ab
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:27 memory:f3500000-f351ffff memory:f353b000-f353bfff ioport:6080(size=32)
```

```
uname -mr
```

```
4.4.0-22-generic i686
```

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
```

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [17aa:21f3]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

```
dpkg -l | grep bcmwl
```

__

```
apt-cache show bcmwl* | grep Version

    Version: 6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8
```

__

And now two taken while networking is working:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [17aa:21f3]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

    --
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 [8086:0891] (rev c4)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 BGN [8086:4222]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

```
        *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 04
       serial: 3c:97:0e:40:5d:ab
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:27 memory:f3500000-f351ffff memory:f353b000-f353bfff ioport:6080(size=32)
    *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 2200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: c4
       serial: 9c:4e:36:6b:4c:84
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-22-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.0.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:29 memory:f2c00000-f2c01fff
```

```
dmesg | grep -e e100 -e enp
```

```
[    1.892860] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    1.892862] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.930561] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    2.193690] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: registered PHC clock
[    2.193694] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 3c:97:0e:40:5d:ab
[    2.193695] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    2.193748] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 10, PHY: 11, PBA No: 1000FF-0FF
[    2.194512] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: renamed from eth0
[   29.556939] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[   29.812008] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[  203.917389] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Down
[ 3059.332464] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[ 3059.587935] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
```

I'm not sure what is going on that the networking would sometimes not work and once in awhile start working.
Also, the last two restarts I have disabled networking before restart, and enabled after boot up, and networking has worked. ?
Thank you for the help. Let me know for any more logs please!

Edit June 28: After updating Ubuntu again networking is not working at all... Any ideas???

Edit July 31: Same symptoms after many updates. Am able to get wireless occasionally on reboot, and haven't found any pattern so far as to why.

Comment: May we please see, when it stops working: `dmesg | grep -e e100 -e enp` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Comment: Same issue, network does not disappear on my side but it's not working